# jQuery send AJAX response data post another php page

Tags: jquery, sugarcrm

I need to send JSON data on AJAX response(of existing function) to another PHP page. Following is code which i have tried.

**script**

```
function printPDF(task){
  var fdata = {"record":"'.$this->bean->id.'"};
  var params = jQuery.param(fdata);
  $.ajax({
    type:"post",
    data: fdata,
    dataType: "json",
    url:"index.php?module=ginvo_client_invoice&action=printinvoice",
    error:function(resp){},
    success:function(resp){
      var invlist = JSON.stringify(resp);
      //console.log(resp);
      $.post("custom/clientinvoice.php", {result:invlist}, function(data) {
            console.log(data);
      });
    }
  });
```

Comment: " I'm try to json data ajax response data post another php page" ... did you write that with a random word generator? ... what exactly do you want? What error do you receive?

Comment: What's the issue?

Comment: ajax response data pass in php file xhr method. I try to print particular php file error issue display.

Comment: @AdamJose well you can redirect it from the server. Why do you want to redirect from front end. 

I'm not saying it's not possible you can pass it via url parameter but it would  be better if you redirect from the server side and pass data from there

Comment: post complete code(including custom page where you are sending ajax call) and edit your question inorder to explain your problem in better way.